# Spark in memory when using SparkSession with enableHiveSupport

Tags: apache-spark, memory, hive, apache-spark-sql

I want to know, when we use SparkSession with enableHiveSupport, does the spark maintain the whole data from the Hive table in memory or just the Dataset that we get as ResultSet after firing the hive query.

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue about how Spark works.

First I will suggest you to read [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)

About to store the table in memory, this will not happens until you call `cache()` method as you can see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#caching-data-in-memory).

When you call `enableHiveSupport()` you are taking access to the metadata of your tables. All informations that is not the real data. When you call the [transofrmations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#transformations) you will handle only the metadata to find the most efficient way to execute your data. When you call [actions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions) this will load your data from hive, load what is necessary to memory and will sotore the final data in memory just if you request.

I really suggest you to do a deep reading at the [Quick Start Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html)

Comment: The answer is not that helpful and basically points to documentation. In fact the documentation doesnt really talk to how Hive and Spark work together in a clear way. The answer should talk to whether Spark takes the data from hive (after all the lazy evaluation) and runs the query in memory or does it simply push the query to hive to be run in the traditional map-reduce fashion.